# jquery not() function not working on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery not to remove html of elements. 
I don't get jQuery not() work in proper way. It removes all elements from children except the last one that I mentioned.

**My Html**-

```
<body>
    <div id="edit-save-section">
        <button id="edit-button" class="btn btn-info btn-large">
            <span><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>&nbsp;EDIT</span>
        </button>
        <button class="division-twenty btn btn-success btn-large" data-loading-text="Saving..." class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save"><span><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;SAVE</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Link1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Link2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Link3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Link4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="removable-section">

        <a href="javascript:;" class=" pull-right span1 handle" rel="tooltip" title="Arrange section" data-placement="left"><b><i class="fa fa-arrows fa-2x"></i></b></a>
        <a class="span1 pull-right remove-section-action" rel="tooltip" title="Remove section" data-placement="left" href="javascript:;"><b><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></b></a>
    </div>

    <div id="allhtml"></div>
</body>
```

**Clearing html with jQuery-**

```
 $('#btn_save').click(function () {
     var notAll = $('body').children().not("#menu", ".removable-section", "#edit-save-section").html();
     $('#allhtml').append(notAll);
     console.log($('#allhtml').html());
 });
```

Somehow I managed removing `#menu` and `.removable-section` , But I can't remove `#edit-save-section`

And If i try to change order of these sections like-

```
 var notAll = $('body').children().not("#menu","#edit-save-section",".removable-section").html();
```

Then it acts weird. It doesn't remove from body the last children found in above html structure. Here in this case it is `.removable-section`.

Let me know what is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: There isn't anything in the markup called `#edit-save-section`???

Comment: there is a `edit-save-button` not a `edit-save-section`

Comment: Try passing a single string with comma separated selectors (which is what the function expects), rather than three individual strings.

Comment: also `"#menu, .removable-section, #edit-save-section"`

Comment: After editing here, please change your actual code too and check Is it working correctly?

Comment: @OomphFortuity, Yes My actual html is what I have here now, And this still doesn't work

Comment: Hi jquery not function accepts  a DOM element, or an array so
replace this 
$('body').children().not("#menu","#edit-save-section",".removable-section").html();

with 

$('body').children().not( "#menu,#edit-save-section,.removable-section").html();

try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use JQuery Clone to achieve this

```
$('#btn_save').click(function () {
     var notAll = $('body').clone(true);
     notAll.find("#menu").remove();
     notAll.find(".removable-section").remove();
     notAll.find("#edit-save-section").remove();
     $('#allhtml').append(notAll);

 });
```